# Plot in Future (Pine Script)

Tags: pine-script

Guys i have done some calculation and imported them all to array.

All the plot lines work great and perfect. But i want to **extend them to future**. Because each day value is changed.
I have tried **offset** but it moves all calculations ahead. I want plot to show future without offset. Any possible way?

Comment: This is not possible now